Microsoft.ManagedIdenitity not found for a api version
I am getting this error when trying to create a new user assigned managed idenitity

var resourceClient = new Azure.Management.ResourceManager.ResourceManagementClient(ClientCredential);

resourceClient.SubscriptionId = SubscriptionId.ToString();

var result = resourceClient.Resources.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ResourceGroup.Name, "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity", "", "userAssignedIdentities", IdentityName, "2023-01-31", identity).GetResult();

System.Exception: The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity' for api version '2022-01-31-PREVIEW'. ---> Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The resource type could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity' for api version '2022-01-31-PREVIEW'.

I checked in the providers version I added is present and also I tried with all other version that are present, but error persists
Can someone please help with this

I have used the below code to create user assigned managed identity.
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.ManagedServiceIdentities;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;

TokenCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
ArmClient client = new ArmClient(cred);

string subscriptionId = "{subscriptionId}";
string resourceGroupName = "{resourceGroupName}";
ResourceIdentifier resourceGroupResourceId = ResourceGroupResource.CreateResourceIdentifier(subscriptionId, resourceGroupName);
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroupResource = client.GetResourceGroupResource(resourceGroupResourceId);

UserAssignedIdentityCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetUserAssignedIdentities();

// invoke the operation
string resourceName = "{resourceName}";
UserAssignedIdentityData data = new UserAssignedIdentityData(new AzureLocation("eastus"))
    {
    Tags =
        {
            ["key1"] = "value1",
            ["key2"] = "value2",
        },
    };
ArmOperation<UserAssignedIdentityResource> lro = await collection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, resourceName, data);
UserAssignedIdentityResource result = lro.Value;

UserAssignedIdentityData resourceData = result.Data;
// for demo we just print out the id
Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded on id: {resourceData.Id}");

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.11.0-beta.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager" Version="1.12.0-beta.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.ResourceManager.ManagedServiceIdentities" Version="1.2.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Given code creates the user assigned managed identity successfully.


References-
azure-sdk-for-net/sdk/managedserviceidentity/Azure.ResourceManager.ManagedServiceIdentities/samples/Generated/Samples/Sample_UserAssignedIdentityCollection.cs · GitHub.

How to retrive a UserAssignedIdentity varible for a created idenitity from this UserAssignedIdentityData as I couldnt see any getasync methods or constructors related.

@ranger check the link I have added as Reference, you can get the code to retrieve the user assigned identities using UserAssignedIdentityResource

code link gives the useridenitity list. I need UserAssignedIdenitity class variable to add to the ManagedServiceIdentity class varaible. ManagedServiceIdentity is required to add it as an authentication type. Is there any way to retrive the UserAssignedIdenitity  variable

@ranger Do you want to retrieve the client id and principal id?

No I retrived principal id and client id
But I need to add the created user assigned managedidenitity to the exisiting redis resource
This is the format of idenitity Azure.ResourceManager.Models.ManagedServiceIdentity.
How to create this ManagedServiceIdentity for the new managed identity.
It asks for UserAssignedIdentities varaible, but I was not able to create that variable as it dont have any get exisiting methods

or is there anyother way to add it directly to exiisting redis resource without creating ManagedServiceIdentity variable

@ranger Do you want to add the created user assigned identity here programmatically?

yes, I need to add the user assigned identity there programmatically.
RedisCollection collection = resourceGroupResource.GetAllRedis();
RedisResource redisResource = collection.GetAsync(clusterName).GetResult();
to this redisResource

Is it possible to add it programmatically

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
